# Why is my CASE statement for Access failing?

Tags: sql, ms-access

```
SELECT c.AssetClass, SUM(c.MarketValue) AS MVCurrent, SUM(p.MarketValue) AS MVPrior, SUM(c.MarketValue) / SUM(p.MarketValue) AS PercentageVariation,
    CASE
    WHEN SUM(c.MarketValue) / SUM(p.MarketValue) BETWEEN 0.9 AND 1.1
    THEN 'PASS'
    ELSE 'FAIL'
    END AS Result
FROM [Nov] AS p, [Dec] AS c
;
```

Is it something to do with the double tables?

Comment: Well, you should be using a `group by` clause when using aggregation.  And you should also be using a `join` clause with multiple tables.  Hard to tell you for sure without knowing your table structure (and possibly sample data and expected results).

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. That will help me figure it out. I'll upload an answer when I get it.

Comment: `CASE` is not supported in Access SQL.  Use an `IIf()` expression instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DATEDIFF With CASE Statement blank](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36081110/datediff-with-case-statement-blank)

Comment: That's a case expression, not a case statement. Not supported anyway, as HansUp already said.